# Invalid Version: Ember-Cli-Babel

Tags: ember.js, npm, ember-cli

Tried upgrading my ember project from ember 2.12.2 to 2.13.2 but I get the following error when I run `ember init`

```
    Invalid Version: https://registry.npmjs.org/ember-cli-babel/-/ember-cli-babel-6.1.0.tgz

    TypeError: Invalid Version: https://registry.npmjs.org/ember-cli-babel/-/ember-cli-babel-6.1.0.tgz

at new SemVer (/Users/code/website/node_modules/semver/semver.js:293:11)
    at Range.test (/Users/code/website/node_modules/semver/semver.js:1036:15)
    at Function.satisfies (/Users/code/website/node_modules/semver/semver.js:1085:16)
    at Class.Addon.(anonymous function) (/Users/code/website/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/addon.js:1547:25)
    at Class.init (/Users/code/website/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/addon.js:234:57)
    at Class.superWrapper [as init] (/Users/code/website/node_modules/core-object/lib/assign-properties.js:34:20)
    at Class.CoreObject (/Users/code/website/node_modules/core-object/core-object.js:9:15)
    at Class (/Users/code/website/node_modules/core-object/core-object.js:21:5)
    at Class (/Users/code/website/node_modules/core-object/core-object.js:21:5)
    at graph.topsort.vertex (/Users/code/website/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/addons-factory.js:55:21)
```

Yet when I run `npm install ember-cli-babel` I still get the error but I also get that the current version is `ember-cli-babel@5.2.4`

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this took a few days but I figure I would document it properly since Ember-Cli docs don't go into it too deep.

When upgrading Ember project before `ember init` I had to delete my `package-lock.json` file then delete all `node_modules`.  Run `npm install` and then `ember init` to run through rewrites/diffs in my code.

Answer (score 0):

When using ember 2.13 you need to upgrade ember-cli-babel to version 6.0.0 or higher . Check your package.json file and update it. If you have problems please include your package.json file in your question above. 
If it does not work, try to remove your `node_modules` folder and reinstall your dependencies with `npm install`.

Comment: I had to delete the`package-lock.json` file.  I checked the `package.json` and it was listing the correct version required, and compared it to a newly generated ember app. `npm` is very slippery with upgrades unfortunately.