# How do I upgrade ember-cli-babel?

Tags: npm, ember.js, ember-cli

The online NPM documentation does not explain how to upgrade `ember-cli-babel`. I tried following the accepted answer posted here [Invalid Version: Ember-Cli-Babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44664737/invalid-version-ember-cli-babel), but that did not work.

> DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade
>   to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: library-ui ->
>   ember-clean-tmp -> ember-cli-babel

**Update**

I have uninstalled the `Ember-clean-tmp` add-on. When I run `Ember-cli-update` I get a message that says `Tags match, nothing to apply`. I then ran `Ember S` and get the following warnings:

> WARNING: ember-basic-dropdown attempted to include external babel
>   helpers to make your build size smaller, but your root app's
>   ember-cli-babel version is not high enough. Please update
>   ember-cli-babel to v7.3.0-beta.1 or later.
>
> WARNING: ember-power-select attempted to include external babel
>   helpers to make your build size smaller, but your root app's
>   ember-cli-babel version is not high enough. Please update
>   ember-cli-babel to v7.3.0-beta.1 or later.
>
> WARNING: ember-data attempted to include external babel helpers to
>   make your build size smaller, but your root app's ember-cli-babel
>   version is not high enough. Please update ember-cli-babel to
>   v7.3.0-beta.1 or later.
>
> WARNING: ember-basic-dropdown attempted to include external babel
>   helpers to make your build size smaller, but your root app's
>   ember-cli-babel version is not high enough. Please update
>   ember-cli-babel to v7.3.0-beta.1 or later.
>
> WARNING: ember-text-measurer attempted to include external babel
>   helpers to make your build size smaller, but your root app's
>   ember-cli-babel version is not high enough. Please update
>   ember-cli-babel to v7.3.0-beta.1 or later.
>
> WARNING: ember-power-select attempted to include external babel
>   helpers to make your build size smaller, but your root app's
>   ember-cli-babel version is not high enough. Please update
>   ember-cli-babel to v7.3.0-beta.1 or later.

**Update 2**

I was able to fix the issue by uninstalling `ember-cli-babel` and re-installing it, which got me to version 7.5.0. But, is this the correct way to upgrade packages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem that you are experiencing is related to one of your addon's depending on an older version of `ember-cli-babel`.

From the deprecation notice, it's [ember-clean-tmp](https://github.com/aalasolutions/ember-clean-tmp/blob/master/package.json), which doesn't look to be up to date. You have a number of options here. First, you could stop using the addon (which in this case doesn't really seem like a necessary addon. Needing to clear my tmp has never been a problem for me in my 2.18 app).

Secondly, if you'd like to keep using the addon, you could go through the process of upgrading the addon's `ember-cli` version to a version that includes a high enough `ember-cli-babel` version. Basically, each `ember-cli` version has a default blueprint for what dependencies a new app should include. When you ugprade, you diff your dependencies and various files against the default for that ember-cli version. [ember-cli-update](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-update) is an addon that makes this process nice. You can then point at your own fork or better yet, get your update merged upstream in `ember-clean-tmp`

Comment: Thank you for the response and explanation. I uninstalled the `ember-clean-tmp` add-on. However, when I ran `ember-cli-update` afterwards, it says that `tags match, nothing to apply`. See question update.

Comment: What exactly kick started this whole process for you? We're you trying to upgrade ember/ember cli? Did you do a new `npm/yarn install`?

Comment: This: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54830949/omnisharp-not-functioning-properly-in-one-project-but-is-in-anotherI . I solved that problem and performed an Ember update via `NPM audit fix`. Then, I started getting the deprecation errors. I fixed the problem by uninstalling babel and reinstalling it. My question is whether babel can be upgraded/updated without reinstalling.

Comment: You probably changed a number of dependencies if you were using `^` and reinstalled via `npm`. It's best to be intentional about upgrades. In general, you don't upgrade `ember-cli-babel` specifically. Rather, you upgrade to a later version of ember-cli using `ember-cli-update` which let's you know that the later version of `ember-cli` requires a newer version of `ember-cli-babel`

Answer (score 1):

Open you Command Prompt and type `ember install ember-cli-babel` and press enter. If you have already installed, don't worry. This will over write.

Reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-babel

Answer (score 0):

First,

```
npm install ember-svg-jar
```

Second,

```
ember install ember-svg-jar
```

All I had to do were these commands.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).